# How to refer to a file added to a setup, before installation?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, freepascal

I am creating a setup file using Inno setup and I would like to add a file to that setup, say 'key.txt' that contains the license key for that setup file. Once the user tries to install using that setup, it prompts for a license key. When the user enters it, i need the setup to read the license key from key.txt and validate the user-entered value. This validation is done done before installation begins. How do I do that?

I added the key.txt to my [Files] section but I do not know how to reference it within the LoadStringFromFile() function, before installation. After installation it will be referred as {app}\key.txt, but before? I cannot give the absolute path right?

Comment: You can extract any file contained in the archive by the `ExtractTemporaryFile` function. But, the user will be able to find that file in the setup's temp folder. Also, there's a way to unpack the setup archive without the need to run it, so storing that key in a file is pretty easy to hack.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much :) So there should also be a way to delete the file permanently from the archive after reading from it right?

Comment: Or modify the file in the setup archive directly?

Comment: I am not storing the key directly, it is stored after encrypting it with an algorithm. So the original key wont be visible to the user directly, even if he manages to unpack the archive. :)

Comment: Well, then it's safer than I thought. And no, you cannot programatically delete a file from the setup archive (it would be useless anyway). However, to manually delete the file that you've extracted (by calling `ExtractTemporaryFile('key.txt')`) you can use `DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\key.txt'))`.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much! How do I delete a normal file with a hidden attribute? This DeleteFile function doesn't seem to work for that.

Comment: `DeleteFile` works for files with hidden attribute. Are you sure that you have used proper file name ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58421/discussion-between-julyflowers-and-tlama).